# return multiple values in Java as shown in the example

Tags: java, arrays

how can I return two values in java ?

for (int i = 1; i < prob.length; i++)
          {

```
             x=x+xprob[i];
             y=y+yprob[i];

      }

       return x,y;
```

thanks

Comment: There are no tuples in Java.

Comment: In this example, x and y are the same, so you don't need two values.

Answer (score 1):

Either return an isntance of a class whose attributes are x and y, or an array of two elements.

Example :

```
public int[] func ()
{
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    ...
    arr[0] = x;
    arr[1] = y;
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: do you have an example how to return an array plz

Comment: I got this an error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Izzy You'll have to show me the code where you got this exception.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
  setUpMyCSVArray ();
   double arr1[][] = new double[36][29];
      double arr2[][] = new double[3][27];
      seriesDistance(arr1, arr2);
   
 }

Comment: btw, I return the two value in this way      String xString = Double.toString(x);
          String yString = Double.toString(y);
          String xyvalue="the value of x is"+ xString +"the value of y is" + yString  ;
          return xyvalue;
        }

Comment: @Izzy what about the code of `seriesDistance` and `setUpMyCSVArray ();`? the exception is probably thrown by one of them.

Comment: Yup it's in the seriesDistance ,what would u suggest to make it like an object